# IOS : where to download uikit and foundation framework

Tags: ios, xcode

I accidentally deleted my uikit and foundation frameworks.Its not present in Xcode.I know i can add it via build phase, But where can i get those frame works?thanks

Comment: Reinstall developer tools if thats what you really did.

Comment: okk I will do that

Comment: Has it been broken for 8 years? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just reinstall Xcode. Should embed the uikit and foundation frameworks the correct way and in their correct place.

Just did a bit of research and its better if you uninstall / reinstall. there are multiple versions of the foundation framework on google and you don't want to mess with adding them via developer tools

~/End of Line

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you use the new version of [Xcode 4.3.x](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/xcode/id497799835?l=en&mt=12) which is available on the App Store. This will install directly into your `/Applications` folder. So re-installing is much easier than it used to be with previous installer-based versions:

1. Delete `/Applications/Xcode.app`
2. [Install Xcode](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/xcode/id497799835?l=en&mt=12) again from the AppStore.

This should fix your problem because the said frameworks reside here (inside the App package):

```
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

Answer (score 3):

It's annoying that every time Xcode upgrade, those system frameworks will move to a new folder.

Actually, we can using image command in lldb to tell you where the framework is:

```
(lldb) image lookup -name "removeFromSuperview"
....
....
22 matches found in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore:
        Address: UIKitCore[0x00000000004a6b73] (UIKitCore.__TEXT.__text + 4866259)
        Summary: UIKitCore`-[UISegment removeFromSuperview]        Address: UIKitCore[0x00000000006267d9] (UIKitCore.__TEXT.__text + 6438201)
        Summary: UIKitCore`-[UICalloutBarButton removeFromSuperview]        Address: UIKitCore[0x000000000062924a] (UIKitCore.__TEXT.__text + 6449066)
.....
```

now we can see, UIKit.framework is found in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore`